How can I return search results snippets from a Microsoft Graph JSON query?
Problem: review search results snippets without opening files
I need to open a potentially large number of files and run multiple searches on each file. I'm trying to return search results snippets like the following, so I can determine result relevance without manually opening the associated files.
NOTE: I need to do this without admin permissions, though for files I can access.

this is an example results snippet with the [SEARCH HIT] in the middle of the snippet

What I've tried
Extended internet research and Gen AI prompting has proved fruitless. From Gen AI (hallucinations?), I've tried using the content field and at least two seemingly fictious fields, hitHighlights and snippets. I also spoke with an experienced colleague who believes what I'm looking for is impossible, at least without admin permissions.
Sample JSON query
The following query works fine. I hope I'm just missing a "results snippet" field or similar functionality to get what I need:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query

{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "filename:(ID1 OR ID2 OR ID3) 
                filetype:pdf AND 
                (searchTerm1 OR searchTerm2 OR searchTerm3) AND path:\"folder/path\""
            },
            "fields": [
                "listId",
                "title",
                "weburl"
                # I'm hoping a magical field here will get what I need
            ],
            "from": 0,
            "size": 500
        }
    ]
}


Microsoft Graph API does not return search result snippets or hit highlights in the response. You can only get the metadata of the files that match the search criteria. The metadata fields that can be returned in the search response are listed in the Microsoft Graph API documentation. Looking at your scenario, you may need to take a longer route if you would like to get more details or content of the file-meaning another API call to get the file content. For example, to download or read the content of the file, you can use the following endpoint:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}/content
Where {item-id} is the id of the file that you get from the search response and be sure to note the required permissions. Related documentation: Download DriveItem content - Microsoft Graph v1.0
If you need to extract specific snippets from the file content based on the search terms, you will need to do it programmatically in your application after getting the file content.
